# Magento 2.2.5 tax import - says successful but nothing in the tax rules or the SQL table - where are errors logged?

Tags: magento-2.2.5

I have tried importing tax rules and although it says successful via the `system>import` tax module - nothing has been imported.  Checked the table to make sure but nothing is there.  I have looked in the normal log files to see if I can see any errors but nothing visible.

I tested by exporting the existing tax rates (this is a clean 2.2.5 install so just the standard 3 US rates available) - changed the name and rates and imported.  Still says imported successfully but nothing to be seen.

Any advice on where I might find the errors or is the command line option I can try where I will see any errors?

Any clues or advice very welcome.

```
Code Country State Zip/Post Code Rate Zip/Post is Range Range From Range To default

US CA * Rate 2 US CA * 9.1    
US NY * Rate 2 US NY * 9.2    
US MI * Rate 2 US MI * 9.3
```

Comment: Was this problem ever resolved? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/139294)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/139294)

Comment: @Michael - not for me. Just entered all again manually !!